# Cant create a branch from a TFS project

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I started using TFS and I was not using branches for my project, but now I need to manage releases, so my Idea is to make Branch from the project and for every release create new branch from the main branch.. so

In VS2015 Source Control Explorer, i click on TFS project > Branching and Marging > Convert To Branch and this error happened

```
TF203028: You cannot create a branch at $/ProjectA because a branch alreadyexists at $/ProjectA/Main. If $/ProjectA/Main is not a branch convert it back to a folder and retry the operation.
```

the problem is that I don't see any branches in source control manager neither in TFS website, I created empty branch earlier but I deleted it. What to do ? I don't want to create new project with Main branch and copy/paste the source codes because I want to preserve the commits.

Comment: " I created empty branch earlier but I deleted it." - What did you call that empty branch. If it was "Main" then that would explain the error. It looks like you can't rename a deleted branch so you'll have to choose a different name for your new branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TFS, you never really delete anything.  In fact, if you look under Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Team Foundation Server, there is an option to show deleted items:

[image: Team Foundation Source Control Settings]

To actually delete an item, have a look at the [tf destroy command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control).

I believe that you can simple rename the folder, and that will maintain your history, should you not wish to permanently delete the old branch.

Comment: Thank you, I undelete the Main branch > make a folder from it and create a branch from the project. That worked.

Answer (score 1):

Potential scenario

Lets say you have branch

```
$/project1/Folder/subfolder/branch1/source
```

You've decided that you need to have

```
$/project1/Folder/branch2/source
```

In this case, first you move the `source` under `subfolder` and now you have 2 items

```
$/project1/Folder/subfolder/branch1 
$/project1/Folder/subfolder/source
```

You say, ok, "I can now delete `branch1`". Delete it and You get

```
$/project1/Folder/subfolder/source
```

All you have to do now is rename `subfolder` to `branch2` and convert it to branch. And this is where you get this error `TF203028: You cannot create a branch at...`

The solution is - in the Source Control Explorer, press button "Show/Hide Deleted Items" to view deleted items, find the deleted `branch1` and convert it to folder using menu "Branching and Merging". Once deleted branches eliminated under your new branch folder, you will be able to convert folder `branch2` to branch. And you don't need `tf destroy` to achieve this result.